# Automapper: Do not map path

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there any simple way to tell automapper to only create a parent object if any of its properties has been mapped?

Imagine this simplistic model

```cs
public class ShoppingCart
{
   List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item 
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   int Price { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
   string Id { get; set; }
   Pizza Pizza { get; set; }
}

public class Pizza
{
   int Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map shopping cart to order. Simply said, the Order.Pizza.Price should have the value mapped from the price of an item called "pizza" in the shopping cart. If there is no item named "pizza" i want the pizza in order to be null instead of an empty/default object

So, these would be the test cases

```cs
    [Test]
    public void Test_WithPizza()
    {
        // Arrange
        var cart = new ShoppingCart()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item() { Name = "Cola", Price = 10 },
                new Item() { Name = "Pizza", Price = 20 }
            }
        };

        //Act
        var order = Mapper.Map<ShoppingCart, Order>(cart);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(order);
        Assert.IsNotNull(order.Pizza);
        Assert.AreEqual(20, order.Pizza.Price);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_WithoutPizza()
    {
        // Arrange
        var cart = new ShoppingCart()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item() { Name = "Cola", Price = 10 }
            }
        };

        //Act
        var order = Mapper.Map<ShoppingCart, Order>(cart);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(order);
        Assert.IsNull(order.Pizza); // Fails
    }
```

My mapping profile looks like this. The condition does not seem to effect whether the parent object (Pizza) is instantiated or not.

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
  public MyProfile()
  {
    CreateMap<ShoppingCart, Order>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(_ => Guid.NewGuid()))
      .ForPath(dest => dest.Pizza.Price, opt =>
      {
        opt.MapFrom(src => GetPizzaPrice(src));
        opt.Condition(con => GetPizzaPrice(con.Source) != null);
      });
  }

  private static int? GetPizzaPrice(ShoppingCart cart)
    => cart.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "Pizza")?.Price;
}
```

Comment: You can do it without `ForPath`, with `ForMember` Pizza and `MapFrom`.

Comment: How would the condition look like if there are many properties?

Comment: However you're able to write it. But I'd guess different child objects have different conditiions, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: I removed my answer. I understand what you're asking but I can't entertain an hypothetical scenario until all of your requirements are met.